# Principal Component Analysis: eigenvectors that maximise variance

Tags: variance, pca, eigenvalues

I am currently starting to learn about Principal Component Analysis. In a presentation, the following is said:

> Let $\mathbf{X} \sim (\mathbf{\mu}, \Sigma)$, $(\lambda_k, \mathbf{\eta}_k)$ the $k$th eigenvalue-eigenvector pair of $\Sigma$ with $k \le r$, and $r$ the rank of $\Sigma$. Then $(\lambda_k, \eta_k)$ satisfy:
>
> 1. $\mathbf{\eta}_1$ maximises the variance of $\mathbf{\eta}^T\mathbf{X}$ over all unit vectors $\mathbf{\eta} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and the variance of $\chi_1 = \mathbf{\eta}_1^T \mathbf{X}$ is $\lambda_1$;
> 2. $\mathbf{\eta_2}$ maximises the variance of $\mathbf{\eta}^T \mathbf{X}$ over all unit vectors $\mathbf{\eta} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ that are orthogonal to $\mathbf{\eta}_1$, and the variance of $\chi_2 = \mathbf{\eta}_2^T \mathbf{X}$ is $\lambda_2$; and,
> 3. for $k \le d$, $\mathbf{\eta}_k$ maximises the variance of $\mathbf{\eta}^T \mathbf{X}$ over all unit vectors $\mathbf{\eta} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ that are orthogonal to the eigenvectors $\mathbf{\eta}_\mathscr{l}$ with $\mathscr{l} \le k - 1$, and the variance of $\chi_k = \mathbf{\eta}_k^T \mathbf{X}$ is $\lambda_k$.

Points 1. and 2. seem to come out of nowhere and be completely arbitrary. I mean, why should $\mathbf{\eta}_1$, of all the eigenvectors, be the one that maximises the variance? And by the same reasoning, why should $\mathbf{\eta}_2$ maximise the variance over all unit vectors that are orthogonal? I'm sure that there is coherent reasoning behind this, but it was not presented, so it seems very arbitrary. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Comment: You put the eigenvalues in descending order, so $\eta_1$ corresponds to the eigenvalue with the largest value.

Comment: @Dave I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You diagonalize the covariance matrix and get three eigenvalues. Put them in ascending order. The eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue is $\eta_1$.

Comment: @Dave Where did this idea of ascending/descending order come from?

Comment: You're goal is to find the eigenvector in the direction of maximum (or second-maximum or least, etc) variance.

Comment: Another way to put this is that the set of eigenvalues doesn't have any *intrinsic* ordering, so by universal (?) convention people typically assume that they are arranged in descending order.

Comment: @BenBolker oh, so it’s just a matter of convention. Thanks for the clarification.